# JavaScript: как создать переменную через функцию?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в JavaScript создать и назначить переменной имя,  переданной через аргумент функции?

Например:

```
function create_el(name){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = name;
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
    //name = document.getElementById(div);  //name должен стать test
}

 create_el('test');
 console.log(test);   // созданный элемент
```

Т.е. нужно в функцию передать имя, а на выходе получить переменную с этим именем.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте глобальную переменную в свойстве window. Например: function(a){window.a=a}. Далее просто используйте её.

Answer (score 7):

Не засоряйте глобальную область видимости такими переменными. Просто возвращайте из функции созданный объект и работайте с ним.

```
function create_el(name){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = name;
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
    return div;
}

console.log(create_el('test'));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    name = 'test'
    window[name] = 'Wow!'
    console.log(test)
```

Но так делать нельзя. Смотри объяснения в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671895/223714